# Neigh effect when playing a unicorn

Tags: unstable-unicorns

If I Play a Unicorn from my hand to my stable, is it possible for another player to neigh this action?
And if it is possible will the unicorn be moved to the discard pile?

Answer (score 2):

[image: Neigh Card]

I've never played this game but looking up the card it seems clear. The text on a neigh card says :-

> Play this card when any player tries to play a card. Stop that
> player's card from coming into play and send it to the discard pile
> instead.

So yes, it is possible for another player to 'neigh' playing a unicorn from hand to stable.

Also yes, it will be moved to the discard pile.